# ReactJS with useEffect not rendering each state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out React's new `useEffect` "[hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)" by using it to control a modal entering and exiting the DOM with some animation.

Here's a working codepen:

https://codepen.io/nicholasstephan/pen/roprgw

and a simplified version:

```
const isOpen = props.isOpen;

const [ animState, setAnimState ] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if(isOpen === true && animState === null) {
    setAnimState('entering');
  }

  if(isOpen === true && animState === 'entering') {
    setAnimState('entered');
  }

}, [isOpen, animState]);

if(animState === null) {
  return null;
}

return (
  <div 
    style={{
      opacity: animState === 'entered' ? 1 : 0, 
      transition: 'opacity 200ms ease-in-out'
    }}>
    ...
  </div>
);
```

My thinking is:

1. On the initial render, `animState` is `null` so we return `null`.
2. When isOpen is set to true, the effect fires and the first condition is met, setting `animState` to 'entering'. In this state the component should return some DOM with opacity of `0`.
3. The effect fires again and the second condition is met, setting `animState` to 'entered'. Creating DOM with an opacity of `1`, animated with a css transition.

The trouble, as far as I can tell, is that the DOM is being added with an opacity of 1, as if React is batching the multiple render calls and only updating the DOM once. If you look in the codepen, I'm logging the `animState` on each render, and the "closed" state is logging, but it doesn't seem to be rendering.

Could this be the case? How do I go about ensuring a render has happened before running the effect again?

I'd be interested to hear if there's an entirely better way of doing something like this? But I'm also curious as to what React is doing behind the scenes here and why I'm not getting the entry animation.

Comment: It will help if you can share an example in a CodeSandbox (or similar) that demonstrates the problem. It will make it much easier to verify potential solutions.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I've added a codepen demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe React is doing exactly what you would expect. It is the browser that has slightly surprising behavior.

From [Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions):

> Care should be taken when using a transition immediately after:
>
> - adding the element to the DOM using .appendChild()
> - removing an element's display: none; property.
>
> This is treated as if the initial
>   state had never occurred and the element was always in its final
>   state. The easy way to overcome this limitation is to apply a
>   window.setTimeout() of a handful of milliseconds before changing the
>   CSS property you intend to transition to.

If I change:

```
if(status === true && animState === 'closed') {
  setAnimState('open');
}
```

to:

```
if(status === true && animState === 'closed') {
  setTimeout(()=>setAnimState('open'), 25);
}
```

it seems to work fine. For me, it did **NOT** work if I used a timeout less than 8 milliseconds and the specifics of this behavior probably vary from browser to browser.

Here's the modified codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbQoZO?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit too complex just for animating the opacity, why not store the opacity in a state variable like this :

```
const isOpen = props.isOpen;
const [ opacity, setOpacity ] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    setOpacity(isOpen ? 1 : 0);      
}, [isOpen]);  

return (
  <div 
    style={{
      opacity, 
      transition: 'opacity 200ms ease-in-out'
    }}>
   ...
  </div>
);
```

You can also try the hook `useRef` to update the opacity manually

```
const isOpen = props.isOpen;
const divEl = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (divEl) {
    divEl.current.style.opacity = 1;
  }
}, [divEl]);

if (!isOpen) {
  return null;
}    

return (
  <div 
    ref={divEl}
    style={{
      opacity: 0, 
      transition: 'opacity 200ms ease-in-out'
    }}>
   ...
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've limited it to opacity to simplify the example. The difference also is that in your example the DOM always rendered, but I want it to return null until `isOpen` is true.

Comment: That does work, but won't handle animating exiting. As soon as `isOpen` is set to false the DOM is immediately removed. I didn't show that as that part of my test actually works fine, but I've updated the code now to include it.

Comment: Watching the ref with `useEffect` is an interesting idea. I hadn't thought of that. But won't setting the opacity imperatively mean the div will be re-rendered with an opacity of 0 if any other property changes?

Comment: you are right, you can use a state variable to store the opacity and use `setOpacity(1)` instead of `divEl.current.style.opacity = 1;`

Comment: I updated my first example to handle animating exiting when `isOpen` is false

Comment: I've added a codepen to better show what's going on. What I'm trying to do is pretty much a combination of your two examples, it needs to 1) render null if there's nothing to display, and 2) support entry and exit animation. But more than that, I'm curious as to what react is doing. It seems a render cycle is being skipped, and I'm not sure why.